# PHP global variable seems to cause HTTP 500 error on dev server but not live server

Tags: php

I am in the process of migrating a website that was developed in India, and moving it to another webhost. Not being an expert at PHP has my head hurting from tracing the code. I think I narrowed down the problem to this bit here...

```
<?php include("../config.php"); ?> 
<?php include("../header.php"); 
    if(!empty($_REQUEST)){
        $newsid = $_REQUEST['name'];
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.story_container').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == '<?php print $newsid; ?>' ) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>


<?
}

?>
```

Specifically, if I delete the third and fourth lines, the 500 error goes away and the page loads, although not correctly, with a $newsid item loaded in the main part of the webpage.

If I'm not mistaken, there is a formatting error and looks like it is missing a terminating curly brace? The purpose of the opening and closing php tag at the end just to include a curly brace has me perplexed. If I close the if statement, the 500 error goes away, but again, the page doesn't load with a $newsid item in the main part of the webpage.

I am at a loss and hoping someone can help me troubleshoot this. Thanks!

Almost forgot. I mentioned the site was developed in India because this page in particular I had converted from ANSI format to UTF-8, in case that gives any more clues.

Comment: where is closing bracket of IF statement?

Comment: Sorry, realized that last bit of code didn't format correctly. It is fixed now

Comment: Did you try like this **if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) and $_REQUEST['name']!=""){**

Comment: If I'm not mistaken $_REQUEST['name'] is used to help construct the URL, so the format looks something like this 

`/news/news.php?name=story6`

Comment: Perhaps it's your last php open tag. Do you have short tags enabled in your ini file? You probably should be consistent with `<?php` vs mixing short tags (`<?`) with regular tags (`<?php`).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rasclatt, the issue was that short codes were not enabled.